# Getting incorrrect(?) error when using File.moveTo

Tags: google-apps-script

So this is my code:

```
 var id= data[i][ID];
    if (data[i][MESSAGE]!="") continue;
    var parentgdrive = data[i][PARENTGDRIVE];
    try{
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentgdrive);
      file.moveTo(folder);
      var message = `moved by ${user} on ${time}.`;
      os.getRange(i+1,MESSAGE+1).setValue(message);
      console.log(id+" "+message);
    }catch(e){
      var message = `${user} failed to move.`;
      os.getRange(i+1,MESSAGE+1).setValue(message);
      console.error(id, i,e);
      }
```

Just goes down a list of files and attempts to move them to a shared drive. It works or doesn't work depending on who owns the file. But i'm getting a weird error for some files owned by other individuals on my domain:

> 1IZZ1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx { [Exception: Cannot use this
> operation on a shared drive item.] name: 'Exception' }

Except none of these files are in a shared drive, they are owned by individuals and all part of the same mydrive structure.

Ideas?

Comment: Idea: use advanced drive service

Comment: ok I'll try that

Comment: Can anyone point me to using ADS to move files? Not having much luck.

Comment: You can check on Tanaike's github about moving files in drive via ADS here https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/11/20/moving-file-to-specific-folder-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/insert